# What is the best way to randomly sample key, value pairs from a dictionary?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, random

Suppose one has a dictionary and wants to randomly sample a subset of key/value pairs, what is the best way to do this?

Previously, I would use `random.sample` but apparently this functionality will be deprecated for sets.  Is there existing functionality that can produce the same result?

```
In [1]: dct = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b':[4,5,6], 'c':[7,8,9]}

In [2]:{k:v for k,v in random.sample(dct.items(),1)}
<ipython-input-33-f99661a57cc1>:1: DeprecationWarning: Sampling from a set deprecated
since Python 3.9 and will be removed in a subsequent version.
  {k:v for k,v in random.sample(dct.items(),1)}
Out[2]: {'a': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Comment: `dict([list(dct.items())[random.choice(range(len(dct)))]])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just convert the `set` into a `list`.

```py
import random

dct = {'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6], 'c': [7,8,9]}

# Sample 2 keys from the dict
random.sample(list(dct.items()), 2))
```